# Conditional fill a value in Data frame based on ranges

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-formatting

I want to make groups according to age ranges in a data frame.
I tried:

```
DF$AgeGroup <- ifelse(DF$Age >= 20 & DF$Age <= 29, "G2", NA)
DF$AgeGroup <- ifelse(DF$Age >= 30 & DF$Age <= 39, "G3", NA)
DF$AgeGroup <- ifelse(DF$Aag >= 40 & DF$Age <= 49, "G4", NA)
...
```

but the next line replaces data assigned by the previous code.
I could manage the groupings into separate columns and then merge them but there must be a simple and straightforward way to do so. Can anyone help?

Comment: Look at function `cut`.

Comment: If you really want to use conditional argument, you'll need to use a nested `ifelse(cond1, "A", ifelse(cond2, "B", ifelse(cond3, "C", "D")))` or `case_when(cond1 ~ "A", cond2 ~ "B", cond3 ~ "C")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DF <- data.frame(Age = sample(1:100, 25))

cuts <- c(0, 20, 30, 40, 50, 100)
groups <- c("G1", "G2", "G3", "G4", "G5")

DF$AgeGroup <- cut(DF$Age, breaks = cuts, labels = groups, right = FALSE)

DF

#    Age AgeGroup
# 1   87       G5
# 2   88       G5
# 3   61       G5
# 4    8       G1
# 5   29       G2
# 6   25       G2
# 7   55       G5
# 8   44       G4
# 9   76       G5
# 10  86       G5
# 11  30       G3
# 12  99       G5
# 13  95       G5
# 14  62       G5
# 15  70       G5
# 16  82       G5
# 17  97       G5
# 18  50       G5
# 19  84       G5
# 20  35       G3
# 21  60       G5
# 22  20       G2
# 23   2       G1
# 24  19       G1
# 25  33       G3
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you have to replace NA with the name of the variable, in this case AgeGroup. This way, the ifelse function replaces the FALSE values with the previous ones.

**You have to do this from the second line on**...

```
DF$AgeGroup <- ""
DF$AgeGroup <- ifelse(DF$Age >= 20 & DF$Age <= 29, "G2", NA)
DF$AgeGroup <- ifelse(DF$Age >= 30 & DF$Age <= 39, "G3", DF$AgeGroup)
DF$AgeGroup <- ifelse(DF$Aag >= 40 & DF$Age <= 49, "G4", DF$AgeGroup)
```

...